# Terminology: what is a spun manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology

I have been reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504524) and encountered the words "spun manifold". Now, I know what a spin structure is. I just want to check that "spun manifold" is indeed just a grammatically correct form of "spin manifold" and not "a spin manifold with extra structure".

Comment: At first I wondered if "spun" was a typo for "spin", but it would appear to be intentional in the paper to which you refer.

Comment: "Spun" is the past participle of the verb "to spin". It may also become an adjective such as when accompanying a noun; the perfect example is "spun knot", a term which "spun manifold" seems to be deeply connected.

Comment: Most likely this means a manifold equipped with a particular spin structure. In contrast, a manifold is spin if it merely admits a spin structure.

Answer (score 1):

orientable: oriented <---> spin: spun <--> pin:pun.

Comment: Could you please add a few words to clarify your answer? As it is, even though the point may be clear, it is perhaps a little dry.